# Injecting text contained in file into custom environment

Tags: environments, input

how can I inject text contained in a file `input.tex` into a custom environment. Something like :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{text}{}
\lstnewenvironment{my}{\lstset{language=text}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{my}
\input{input.tex}
\end{my}
\end{document}
```

---

Response to Gonzalo Medina :

Hi, if I use `\lstinputlisting[language=text]{file.tex}` then the comments (appearing after `\\`) are not properly highlighted as comments :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{text}{
commentstyle=\color{green},
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
showstringspaces=false,
showspaces=false,
}

{\catcode`\^^M=12 
\def\marshal{\lstnewenvironment{my}{
\lstset{language=text,comment=[s]{\\\\}{^^M}}
}{}}\expandafter}\marshal

\begin{document}

The following works as expected (comments showing in green): 

\begin{my}
Not comment
\\Commment
Not comment
\end{my}

The following does not work as expected (comments not green):

\lstinputlisting[language=text]{input.text}

\end{document}
```

where `input.text` contains the following code :

```
Not comment
\\Commment
Not comment
```

---

@egreg

From [regular expression in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99414/regular-expression-in-listings) the following code works fine :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstdefinelanguage{text}{}

{\catcode`\^^M=12 \def\marshal{\lstnewenvironment{mylang}{\lstset{language=text,comment=[s]{^^MXYZ}{^^M^^M},commentstyle=\color{green},basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,showstringspaces=false,showspaces=false,}}{}}\expandafter}\marshal

\begin{document}
\begin{mylang}
Only a test, this is not a comment
XYZ this should colored as a comment
and this line too

this is not a command, because only lines starting with XYZ
are comments

This is not a comment, too
\end{mylang}
\end{document}
```

Now what I want to do is to have :

```
Only a test, this is not a comment
XYZ this should colored as a comment
and this line too

this is not a command, because only lines starting with XYZ
are comments

This is not a comment, too
```

Contained in a file, then to load this file into the main tex file and then get the same colouring which I get when the text is contained in the tex file as above. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site.

Comment: Why not, instead of using the `my` environment, just using the optional argument for `\lstinputlisting`? An example: `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{text}{}
\lstnewenvironment{my}{\lstset{language=text}}{}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=text]{file.tex}

\end{document}`

Comment: Please, don't pile up new questions. The problem you have added is completely different.

Comment: @egreg Sorry I was originally trying to load the code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99414/regular-expression-in-listings from a file, and I tried to simplifying the example in order to make it more transparent.

Comment: @egreg Hi I put the question in a separate post : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116368/using-catcode-in-conjunction-with-lstnewenvironment-and-lstinputlisting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do it more simply:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
Not comment
\\Commment
Not comment
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{text}{
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showspaces=false,
  comment=[l]{\\\\},
}

\begin{document}

The following works as expected (comments showing in green): 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=text]
Not comment
\\Commment
Not comment
\end{lstlisting}

The following works as expected (comments showing in green):

\lstinputlisting[language=text]{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity is it possible to inject the code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99414/regular-expression-in-listings via a file? If you try the above for the example there, it does not work since the XYZ identifier is only treated as a newline in environment. Thanks

Comment: @artella Sorry, but I don't get it.

Comment: Hi I have edited my original post (see bottom) to illustrate more clearly what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: I was looking at how to inject a `lstinputlisting` into a custom environment, and, despite the question title, did not find my answer here :( Is there any way to do it less simply and more complicated? :) such that the `lstinputlisting` inherits the properties of the `lstnewenvironment`?

Comment: @macmadness86 I can't understand, sorry.