# Using catcode in conjunction with lstnewenvironment and lstinputlisting

Tags: environments, input

(This is related to [Injecting text contained in file into custom environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116249/injecting-text-contained-in-file-into-custom-environment), but I was asked to put this in a separate post)

From [regular expression in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99414/regular-expression-in-listings) the following code works fine :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstdefinelanguage{text}{}

{\catcode`\^^M=12 \def\marshal{\lstnewenvironment{mylang}{\lstset{language=text,comment=[s]{^^MXYZ}{^^M^^M},commentstyle=\color{green},basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,showstringspaces=false,showspaces=false,}}{}}\expandafter}\marshal

\begin{document}
\begin{mylang}
Only a test, this is not a comment
XYZ this should colored as a comment
and this line too

this is not a command, because only lines starting with XYZ
are comments

This is not a comment, too
\end{mylang}
\end{document}
```

My question is whether it possible to have :

```
Only a test, this is not a comment
XYZ this should colored as a comment
and this line too

this is not a command, because only lines starting with XYZ
are comments

This is not a comment, too
```

Contained in a file, then to load this file into the main tex file and then get the same colouring which I get when the text is contained in the tex file as above. I tried the following but it didnt work :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

{\catcode`\^^M=12 \def\marshal{\lstdefinelanguage{text}{comment=[s]{^^MXYZ}{^^M^^M}}}\expandafter}\marshal

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=text]{input.text}
\end{document}
```

where `input.text` contains the code :

```
Only a test, this is not a comment
XYZ this should colored as a comment
and this line too

this is not a command, because only lines starting with XYZ
are comments

This is not a comment, too
```

Thanks